# Android: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I just bumped the android gradle plugin version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha06` and my project fails to compile with the following error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public inline fun <reified W : `Worker;`> 
PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder(repeatInterval: `Duration;`, 
flexTimeInterval: `Duration;`): PeriodicWorkRequest.`Builder;` defined 
in androidx.work
public inline fun <reified W : `Worker;`> 
PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder(repeatInterval: Long, repeatIntervalTimeUnit: `TimeUnit;`): PeriodicWorkRequest.`Builder;` defined in androidx.work
```

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(1L, TimeUnit.HOURS)
}

class MyWorker: Worker() {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

A sample repo is there: https://github.com/martinbonnin/TestCanary6

Do I miss something or is it an android studio bug ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing a similar issue, but in my case the compiler error says it cannot access to a class in the kotlinx coroutines library ¯_(ツ)_/¯. For now I've reverted the plugin update and I'm building/installing using command line tool.

EDIT: I think it's been tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112723639